# I cannot find where 0002 umask is being set on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, umask

My user account has a non-standard umask setting of 0002, and I cannot find the config file where this is being set.  I have searched in /etc and ~/.bash* with `sudo grep -iIr umask`.  Running umask in a bash shell over ssh is showing 0002, and running it in a root shell via `su - root` gives 0022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, umask 0002 *is* the default for regular users.

It is defined in `/etc/login.defs`, but the definition is in two parts.

First, the `UMASK` setting determines the initial umask for both root and regular users. Note that the comments suggest that a later `USERGROUPS_ENAB` setting will modify it for regular users:

```
# Login configuration initializations:
#
#       ERASECHAR       Terminal ERASE character ('\010' = backspace).
#       KILLCHAR        Terminal KILL character ('\025' = CTRL/U).
#       UMASK           Default "umask" value.
#
# The ERASECHAR and KILLCHAR are used only on System V machines.
# 
# UMASK is the default umask value for pam_umask and is used by
# useradd and newusers to set the mode of the new home directories.
# 022 is the "historical" value in Debian for UMASK
# 027, or even 077, could be considered better for privacy
# There is no One True Answer here : each sysadmin must make up his/her
# mind.
#
# If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK default value
# for private user groups, i. e. the uid is the same as gid, and username is
# the same as the primary group name: for these, the user permissions will be
# used as group permissions, e. g. 022 will become 002.
#
# Prefix these values with "0" to get octal, "0x" to get hexadecimal.
#
ERASECHAR       0177
KILLCHAR        025
UMASK           022
```

And a bit later, in the same file:

```
# Enable setting of the umask group bits to be the same as owner bits
# (examples: 022 -> 002, 077 -> 007) for non-root users, if the uid is
# the same as gid, and username is the same as the primary group name.
#
# If set to yes, userdel will remove the user's group if it contains no
# more members, and useradd will create by default a group with the name
# of the user.
#
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes
```

Debian 11 has the exact same set-up, so Ubuntu 20.04 probably has it too. (I don't currently have a Ubuntu 20.04 VM at hand for checking.)

Classically, all users in a system used to share a primary group (often named `users`) and had a default umask of `0022` - or perhaps `0077` if the system required a hardened security posture.

This makes group projects somewhat awkward: once the sysadmin has created a group for a project and added the relevant users to it, before manipulating any files or directories intended to be accessible by a particular group, users must *always* remember to use `newgrp` or `sg` or else any new or copied files will not be writeable by other group members, which is annoying.

(If an accidentally non-group-writable file is in a group-writable directory, another group member user will be able to rename the problem file and make a copy of it, as long as the file is readable for the second user. Since the second user will be the owner of the new copy, they can now place the new copy where the problematic original was, and adjust its permissions to allow the group project to continue even if the person who accidentally made a project file non-group-writable... but it has been my experience that most users don't know this, and cry for help from the busy system administrator.)

As a result, the *usergroups scheme* was developed. It has two parts:

1. For each regular user, a group is also allocated so that UID = GID. No other users will be assigned to that group.
2. Regular users' default umask is changed to either `0002` or `0007` depending on required security posture.

Now, when a new group project begins, the sysadmin still needs to create a group and assign workspace for the group:

```
groupadd project
for user in user1 user2 user3; do usermod -a -G project $user; done
mkdir -p /shared/project
chgrp project /shared/project
chmod 2770 /shared/project   # results in permissions drwxrws---
```

And now, the users won't need to remember anything special to have the files they create in `/shared/project` be fully accessible to the other group members: it Just Works.

The setgid bit on the top directory of the project causes all new files and directories to be assigned to the project group, and all directories created by the project members will also inherit the setgid bit. Because the users' umasks already allow group write access, the permissions will be correct for group work by default.

When the user manipulates their private files in their home directory, the group-access-enabled umask will cause no problems, because *each user has their own primary group (UID = GID) which has no other members*.

Comment: The USERGROUPS_ENAB flag was the piece I was missing here, thank you! Now I am left wondering why my *other* Ubuntu 20.04 install has 022 for a user account though.

Comment: The USERGROUPS_ENAB changes the umask only if the user's primary GID = UID. If a group has been created without a corresponding user with a GID number 1001 or a little above, instead of something below 1000 or something much higher, it can push the usergroups for users created after it to GID=UID+1 or similarly out of sync. Perhaps something like this has happened with your other Ubuntu?